# Parsing model query results and controller public variable from controller to view with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

Is this posible to send data from controller like this?

Controller test.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Test extends CI_Controller {

        public $data = array(
            'modul'         => 'user',
            'title_meta'    => 'User',
            'breadcrumb'    => 'User',
            'pesan'         => '',
            'pagination'    => '',
            'main_view'     => 'administrator/user',
            'form_action'   => '',
            'form_value'    => '',
        );

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();      
            $this->load->model('test_model', 'test', TRUE);
        }

        public function index()
        {
            $data['query'] = $this->test->get_all();
            $this->load->view('test',$data);
        }

    }
```

Model test_model.php

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Test_model extends CI_Model {

    function get_all() {
        $query = $this->db->get('snb_user');
        return $query->result_array();
    }
}
```

View test.php

```
<?php
foreach($query as $row)
{
    echo $row['UserID'];
    echo $row['UserName'];
    echo $row['UserEmail'];
}

echo $breadcrumb;
?>
```

When i run this, i get this error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: views/test.php
>
> Line Number: 4 A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: views/test.php
>
> Line Number: 4 A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: views/test.php
>
> Line Number: 4 A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: views/test.php
>
> Line Number: 4 A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: breadcrumb
>
> Filename: views/test.php
>
> Line Number: 7

I want to parse data from variable *$data* on controller and the result of sql query from model, is it posible?
Any help would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: check num_rows() of your result-set and  instead of $data user $this->data            
$this->data['query'] = $this->test->get_all();

Comment: i did this `return $query->num_rows();` the result is _4_, view test.php `echo $breadcrumb; echo $query;` , but still get this: 
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: breadcrumb

Filename: views/test.php

Line Number: 2

Comment: use $this->load->view('test',$this->data);

Comment: i have tried `$this->load->view('test',$this->data);`, $breadcrumb variable  sucecsfully showing but sql result wont showing. i get this error _Message: Undefined variable: query_ and _Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()_

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declare varible named `$breadcrumb` in view file or in controller.if you want to remove this notice then you should decalare varible or use [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) or [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) method before using `$breadcrumb` varible.

Comment: $data = array(
            'breadcrumb'    => 'User'
        );
$breadcrumb is defined.!

Comment: you have to use like this `$this->data = array( 'breadcrumb' => 'User');` because you have written like `$this->load->view('test',$this->data);` so now data is member varible instead of local varible.

Comment: i've tried `$this->data = array( 'breadcrumb' => 'User');` , but getting error _Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\sanabudotcom\apps\controllers\test.php on line 5_

Comment: can you paste your function code here.so that i can clearly understand what is there and what problem is there?